# Producing contingency tables having multiple response categorical variables

Tags: gtsummary

Is there anyway to let gtsummary distinguish between a single response categorical variable and a multiple resoibse categorical variable?

From what I have tested, if my categorical variable inclues comma seperated values, then the gtsummary would treat a combination of the values as a single response option in the generated data tables.

e.g. if we have Spoken Languages field

Then the generated data tables will be

| Spoken Languages | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| english arabic | 1 | 6 |
| arabic kurdish | 2 | 6 |
| english kurdish arabic | 3 | 7 |

I want the Spoken Languages column to include the distinct values of that field and not a combination of them

Comment: gtsummary will tabulate what's in the data frame. It looks like you'll need to do some preprocessing to separate the languages into a long format

Comment: Thanks @DanielD.Sjoberg  So if I have an observation like the following  

Spoken Languages  | Sex
------------------------------- 
English Spanish | Female 

Should I convert it to 2 rows?  

OR do you think I should add a binary dummy column to the languages and use them in the cross-tables